# How two build Shapes like this Sunsail?

Tags: modeling

I need help with creating these sun sail shapes, I wasn't able to find a solution on the internet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use a Soft Body or Cloth simulation with pinned corners. Running the simulation will allow it to reach a natural position based on gravity and the stretching forces applied. You can then apply the Soft Body/Cloth modifier to make the shape permanent.

Answer (score 1):

One quick way to fake it is to use a subdivision surface modifier on a simple plane with the basic desired shape of the sunsail, then extrude loose vertex to create some pinching.

Just select a few and vertex on the border of the shape, then use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> > *Vertices only*. Adjust vertex position to create enough stretching and get the ends at the desired place.

[image: Vertex]

If you are looking for a more physically accurate solution you can use the cloth modifier. Subdivide your base shape enough for the desired level of detail, the create a new *Vertex Group* and add all the tip vertex. Turn your mesh into a *Cloth* physics type then use the previously created vertex group in the *Pinning* option.

[image: Cloth]